# How to overlay a new image onto a fixed container when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to replicate this overlay phone effect from this website:

https://www.beemit.com.au/

Basically, when you scroll down, the contents inside the fixed div (phone) also change.

I cannot grasp my head around the revealing effect created when you scroll down. I have only managed to create the fixed div and the various sections on the webpage.

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far, preferably in a StackOverflow snippet. It makes it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version of the overlay-on-scroll.

There are 3 elements, the first image you want to be shown in the 'phone', the second image which gradually gets revealed and the footer element. They have different z-indexes so footer is behind both first and second and second is behind first.

The phone has a fixed position so it doesn't move on scrolling. The footer is placed relative to the body (or whatever container you have) just out of view at 100%.

We introduce a simple event listener on scrolling which tests whether there is an overlap between the footer and the phone. If there is then we set the height of the first image element to be its original height minus the overlap. This reveals the bottom part of the second element.

Without seeing your code I can't tell whether you need more sophistication (for example, you have to be aware of stacking contexts if your phone and footer are not in the same one).

```js
const footer = document.querySelector('.footer');
const first = document.querySelector('.first');
const firstBottom = first.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
const firstHeight = firstBottom - first.getBoundingClientRect().top;

function checkOverlay() {
  const top = footer.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if ( top < firstBottom) {
    first.style.height = firstHeight - firstBottom + top + 'px';
  }
  
}
```

```css
body {
  width:100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.first, .second {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.first {
  background-image: linear-gradient(magenta, pink);
  z-index: 0;
}
.second {
  background-image: linear-gradient(cyan, lime);
  z-index: -1;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red,blue);
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="checkOverlay();">
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```